# Buckets of twater

Tags: philosophy-of-language, essence

I was reading through the SEP article on the [epistemology of modality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modality-epistemology/), which prompted my initial question:

> Is, "Water is H<sub>2</sub>O," currently falsifiable?
> Or are we now in a position where, if we microscopically analyzed a packet of substance and we didn't read out H<sub>2</sub>O, we'd conclude it wasn't water?

The twater idea usually adverts to the equivalent of a parallel universe, so the issue of our biochemistry being compatible with XYZ doesn't arise, but suppose we came across some twater in our same universe. Surprisingly, even when we drink XYZ, our bodies still process it like they would water proper.

This would just be odd, I suppose, but what if we filled a bottle with equal parts H<sub>2</sub>O and XYZ? Let's say we now have a bottle of *twawa*. We swirl the twawa around until the bits of water and twater are uniformly distributed throughout the bottle. We could, with effort, isolate pockets of twawa and separate them back out into their constituents, but this would be more difficult than filtering out sediment, say. At any rate, why isn't the bottle of twawa, really just a bottle of water, and hence how is twater not water? Or, doesn't the bottle of twawa falsify the hypothesis that water is H<sub>2</sub>O?

Or suppose we drank a glass of what microanalysis revealed was plain H<sub>2</sub>O, and it inexplicably, but reliably, caused one of our eyes to turn into a penguin's beak. Like, everyone who drinks glasses of this water, gets a beak. Presumably there would have to be some dark matter or dark energy involved; otherwise, we would seem to have a sample of H<sub>2</sub>O that isn't water (since water proper doesn't cause beak growth in humans).

*My general objection:* but this really just goes to show that the meaning, not of *water*, but of *H<sub>2</sub>O*, is at issue. Basically, if there were parcels of matter that not only macroscopically behaved like water, but could be chemically melded with water proper in the bottle case described above, those parcels of matter *would have to be H<sub>2</sub>O*, on account of that term's own definition, not the definition of *water.* Identifying those parcels as H<sub>2</sub>O depends, in part, on identifying them as macroscopic water beforehand. (But so this might go on to show that the direction of definitions, in the Kripke-Putnam case, goes against the grain of how water and H<sub>2</sub>O are actually interdefined vs. actual scientific discoveries and insights.)

Comment: I just don’t think it’s a hypothesis that water is H2O, “doesn't the bottle of twawa falsify the hypothesis that water is H2O?” Hypothesis implies science and in the scientific description (which water is H20 is not) you’re going to specify exactly what each word is supposed to mean in the theory.  If something has the chemical structure of H20 but produces beaks, there’s no great puzzle-lots of things are H20 and do different things (ice, steam, etc)

Comment: No doubt we'd tend to conclude, "Sometimes, H2O causes beak growth in humans." Or would we say, "This sample of water causes that"? It would be hard to frame, "Water is H2O," as a hypothesis, I suppose; it would have to be something like, "The words *water*, *wet*, etc. typically successfully refer relative to samples of H2O," which could be an empirical proposal about word usage; but I don't see that this would here instantly lend itself to elaborately rigid transworld identities, say.

Comment: I think we’d only say “sometimes, H20 cause beak growth” in the same sense of “technically, a tomato is a fruit”. If we really wanted to be talking about tomatoes when talking of fruit, we’d update our definitions. The working theory or context (culinary, botany, physics, physics post-twawa particles) changes the language.

Comment: I do know that C2H5OH is definitely not interchangeable with water. Although it can cause your nose to grow.

Answer (score 1):

This question has touched on a logic error in most modal thinking, and articulates one of the test cases that illustrates that logic flaw.

The SEP article lists three sets of laws that modal reasoning postulates, laws of nature, laws of metaphysics, and laws of logic.  However, there are strong reasons to think there are no absolute laws in any of these three categories. The cited SEP article in the OP, notes that the existence of metaphysical laws is problematic, and difficult to justify, so I will address the other two more plausible sets of laws.

For "nature", the "laws" of physics at least have been shown, by Noether's Theorem, to be generated by fundamental symmetries in nature.  However, almost all of the symmetries we have found in nature are only *regularities*, not necessities. They are spontaneously broken symmetries, that hold in most cases, but not all.  And our current best physics theory is that ALL of these symmetries will spontaneously break, as they are gauge symmetries, not global symmetries.  https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.93.25.14256  If the symmetries break, then laws would only be regularities, and every one of the laws of physics also breaks.

Additionally, for the rest of science, science is now accepted as pluralistic. See section 5 of:  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-reduction/ But a pluralist base for reasoning, CANNOT produce a coherent set of predicted outcomes.  Science is therefore a pragmatic not a logic field, and does not have the internal consistency to even support "laws of nature".

For "laws of Logic", logicians have recently reached a near consensus that logic is pluralist:  https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/think/article/abs/guide-to-logical-pluralism-for-nonlogicians/EDFDFA1C9EB65DB71848DABD6B12D877  With pluralist logic, there is not a single logic conclusion to logic questions.  Hence, there cannot be "laws of logic" either.

Addressing the example in the question -- is "water == H2O" a logical necessity, the argument in favor depends on both laws of logic and laws of nature being inviolable.  The law of logic assumed is that of reduction, that all physical properties can be reduced to the properties of a material substrate.  The laws of nature assumed is that H2O has an explicit and defined set of properties.

However, as the thought problem notes, physical properties are NOT exclusively reductionist. One can have the same set of properties, with multiple different substrates.  This is the insight of "multiple realizability", that refuted neural identity theory for consciousness, and lead to the postulation of functionalism as an alternative (in functionalism, the postulated identity of consciousness was redefined to be to the function, which could be realized many different ways, not the details of a particular substrate).  Similarly, water could in principle have an XYZ base chemistry, yet still be functionally "water" based on its properties.

Further discussing questions -- define water functionally and not reductively, and yes Twatter is water.  So is a 50/50 mix of the two.

As a pragmatic aspect of our world, there is a large range of impurities that we always find in our H2O, yet the impure mixture still behaves as water.  So our water already is multiply realizable with impurities.  But SOME impurities have significant physiologic consequences on biosystems, even if at the macro level (wetting, density, freezing point) the H2O mixture might behave otherwise like water. Such poisoned water is not "water".  So a sample of H2O that causes one to grow a beak out of an eye, most likely due to a trace bioactive protein catalyst, is functionally not water.

This discussion has mostly focused on the logic aspects of modal thinking incorrectly assuming laws that do not uniformly hold.  One could extend this discussion to physics, where the properties of the Standard Model of Quantum Mechanics are now recognized to be contingent, not necessary.  With contingent "laws" of physics possibly changing in our world over time, or between possible worlds, one could have H2O which does not behave like water.

Modal reasoning is still a useful activity, which the above discussion explains, because these "laws" are regular enough that pragmatically one is usually just fine assuming they are inviolable.   But modal reasoning is only pragmatically "true", not logically true.

Comment: I would say that I am a methodological pluralist wittingly, but I am not sure whether I am a metaphysical pluralist. I always have to be cautious about it because if I push the ambient thought process too far, I would end up with a pluralism about the truth of monism vs. pluralism itself, which would first logically explode, and then logically implode, leaving me with a gristly monism to chew on. I suppose I'm more at the point where the very question of monism-vs.-pluralism seems perhaps incomplete or even downright inadequate to the target issues.

Comment: @KristianBerry -- Before I could embrace pluralism, I had to ditch logical truth, in favor of pragmatism and pragmatic truth.  Yes, pragmatic systems all are subject to logic explosions, because pragmatic truth isn't capable of supporting logical consistency.  But those are the only kinds of systems that can match our world.

Comment: If those are the only kinds of systems that possibly match our world, then it is necessary that no other systems match our world, and we have sailed off into the heights of modality-land again anyway, though, haven't we? I feel like this is one of those, "If every rule has exceptions, then there is an exception to the rule that every rule has exceptions, so there is still an exceptionless rule," kinds of situations.

Comment: @KristianBerry  As an empiricist, I can't show any kind of necessity to this conclusion.  It is an empirical inference.  And empiricism is always uncertain, but that is pragmatically good enough.

Comment: You said "only kinds of systems that can match," which converts over to "other systems must not match," the other systems being less metaphysically (dogmatically?) pluralist. I myself am not overly concerned with certainty *or* uncertainty; or, I do not see that as what is more deeply at stake. There are absolutes that are subjective and objectively relative things besides, and then the other combinations too. There is even room to talk of absolute relativity. But once we attend to more specific questions we are compelled to come up with more refined filters.

Comment: @KristianBerry -- Currently, we don't know how to do science other than pluralistically, logic other than pluralistically, and non-science knowledge other than pluralistically.  However, theory is always underdetermined by evidence, so the reasonable inference that we have to live with pluralism, could change at some time in the future.  Empiricism (IE science and pragmatism), however, operates off what works from our current knowledge, not logical possibilities.

Comment: Ah, but all I mean to say is: is talk of pluralism-vs.-monism meaningful, in the end? Or once we turn to the real questions that haunt us, doesn't that issue fall out of sight, in a way? "Is something else going on?" What is *actually* at stake in all of this?

Comment: In programming, 'modal' means "something that blocks all progress until you dismiss it". Programming is definitely pluralistic at this point, which makes it hard to teach and harder to make choices among alternatives. Hard to even become *aware* of all the possible alternatives. I guess I finally understand Philosophy now. By the way, how many Philosophers does it take to screw in a lightbulb? Well, they can't agree on the definitions.

Comment: @KristianBerry have you looked in to Nonduality?

Comment: It sounds familiar. However, there are some facts in which the arity emphasized is not very important, unary facts in which the number 1 *is* important, binary facts in which the number 2 is important, ternary facts... tetrary, pentary, hexary ... infinitary (any level)... And I don't think any one number, as such, absolutely needs to be more important than any other. I wouldn't think that binary facts were more important overall, or monadic facts either, or countably infinite sets of facts, or wharever.

Comment: @KristianBerry -- for me, I consider the techniques of analytic philosophy, to be an obstacle to doing most philosophy.  This discussion, which notes the invalidity of the Modal thinking which is so central to the school, and the plurality of logic as opposed to its assumed One True Logic, serves as an important insight toward that end.  Quine's Two Dogmas of Empiricism paper notes how no language can ever support analyticity, is another major blow.  I am instead an advocate of pragmatism and empiricism, as a far more useful starting point approach.